# Setting HttpContext.Current using HttpContextBase

Tags: multithreading, dependency-injection, httpcontext

I have a long-running task that I run in a thread. I would like to set the HttpContext.Current in this thread, so my HttpContextFactory can get the current HttpContext.

Here is my TaskRunner class:

```
public class TaskRunner
{
    public TaskRunner(
        IQueueProcessorFactory queueProcessorFactory,
        IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory)
    {
        _queueProcessorFactory = queueProcessorFactory;
        _httpContextFactory = httpContextFactory;
    }

    public void StartQueueProcessorThread()
    {
        var currentContext = _httpContextFactory.Create(); // Simply Gets new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        queueProcessor = new Thread(
        () =>
        {
            HttpContext.Current = currentContext; // Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' to 'System.Web.HttpContext'
            _queueProcessorFactory.Create().ProcessQueue(); // Log running task
        })
        { Name = "QueueProcessor" };
        queueProcessor.Start();
    }
}
```

Is there an easy way to set HttpContext.Current using the injected _httpContextFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible, nor should you try to achieve such thing. Your question is caused by code that is taking a hard dependency on `HttpContext.Current`. This is a Dependency Inversion Principle violation. Since your code is running on a background thread, it is not running in the context of a HTTP request, and should therefore not be using request information.

The solution is to define application-specific abstractions that abstract `HttpContext`. For instance, when that code requires information about the current user, define an `IUserContext` abstraction:

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    Guid UserId { get; }
}
```

This allows you to inject a different `IUserContext` implementation when running on a background thread.

The `IUserContext` implementation for your web requests might look as follows:

```
public sealed class AspNetUserContext : IUserContext
{
    public Guid UserId => (Guid)HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"];
}
```

The user context that you use on the background thread, on the other hand, might be implemented as follows:

```
public sealed class ThreadStaticUserContext : IUserContext
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    public static Guid UserIdField;

    public Guid UserId => this.UserIdField;
}
```

This `ThreadStaticUserContext` allows setting the `UserId`. In case you want to spin off a background thread that runs in the same user ID as the initiating request, you will have to pass the User ID on to the background thread, and set the `FixedUserContext.UserId` value before running the complete operation. This might look like this:

```
public AsynchronousWelcomeMessageSenderDecorator : IWelcomeMessageSender
{
    private readonly IUserContext userContext;
    private readonly Func<IWelcomeMessageSender> senderFactory;

    public AsynchronousWelcomeMessageSenderDecorator(
        IUserContext userContext, 
        Func<IWelcomeMessageSender> senderFactory) { ... }

    public void SendWelcomeMessage(WelcomeMessage message)
    {
        // Read the user ID while running on the request thread
        Guid userId = this.userContext.UserId;

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
        {
            // Set the user ID as the first thing to do on the background thread.
            ThreadStaticUserContext.UserIdField = userId;

            // Resolve the 'real' sender within the thread.
            IWelcomeMessageSender realSender = this.senderFactory();

            // Forward the call to the real sender.
            realSender.SendWelcomeMessage(message);
        });
    }
}
```

To give you an idea, without a DI Container, this part of the object graph could be constructed as follows:

```
IWelcomeMessageSender sender =
    new AsynchronousWelcomeMessageSenderDecorator(
        new AspNetUserContext(),
        () => new EmailMessageSender(new ThreadSpecificUserContext()));
```

In other words, any component that depends on `IWelcomeMessageSender` will get an `AsynchronousWelcomeMessageSenderDecorator` injected. When its `SendWelcomeMessage` is called, it will spin off a background thread, which will request an `IWelcomeMessageSender` through the `senderFactory`. The `senderFactory` will create a new `EmailMessageSender` that will send the actual mail. This `EmailMessageSender` again depends on `IUserContext`, but in this case it is injected with the `ThreadSpecificUserContext`.

Comment: Thank you, @Steven, but I am still a little confused. Say I define `AspNetUserCotnext`, which is the concrete form of `IUserContext. This means that `AspNetUserContext` would eventually depend on `HttpContext.Current`, right? Keep in mind that I don't have access to `IHttpContextAccessor` since I am working on an asp.net 4.6 project.

Comment: this helped me so much!! Much appreciated. One last question: would it make sense to have two interfaces, `IUserContext` and `IThreadStaticUserContext`? Otherwise, how can I instruct my DI container to inject a thread static implementation into a code module that starts a worker thread?

Comment: Which DI Container are you using?

Comment: I am using Unity.

Comment: I'm not sure how to achieve this with Unity, but from a design perspective, it doesn't make sense to create multiple interfaces, since you want the business logic to be oblivious to where it is running. Another option is to merge both implementations into 2. In other words have an implementation that loads from HttpContext except when it is set explicitly.